# How do I present an alertbox in Spritekit?

Tags: sprite-kit, alert

I can't figure out how to get an alert box in Spritekit. This code below used to work but KeyWindow is deprecated, so what do I do now?

```
let currentViewController : UIViewController=UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
```

I have tried:

```
let currentViewController : UIViewController = (self.view?.window!.rootViewController)!
```

any a few other variants, but none seem to work. The alert just wont pop up.

Can someone please shed a bit of light on this issue?

full codeblock:

```
 let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Connect to others", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
 ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host a session", style: .default, handler: startHosting))
 ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join a session", style: .default, handler: joinSession))
 ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

 let currentViewController :
    UIViewController = (self.view?.window!.rootViewController)!

 currentViewController.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, not really sure why it works like this, but it does work.

adding DispatchQueue

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Connect to others", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host a session", style: .default, handler: self.startHosting))
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join a session", style: .default, handler: self.joinSession))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.view?.window?.rootViewController!.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Restore Purchases?", message: "Do you want to restore a purchase?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in

                //run code here when ok button is pressed

                 })

            alert.addAction(ok)
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: this solutions wont bring up the alert box.. I had to add "DispatchQueue.main.async"